# ¿como convertir Oracle multiple join a PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle, join

Este es el fragmento que se quiere convertir, (+) de oracle permiten agrupar join pero el proceso inverso para convertirlo a PostgreSQL lo hace complejo.

```
        SELECT  REQ.ID_REQUEST, REQ.DA_USER, REQ.ID_SOA, SER.DE_NAME, SER.DE_VERSION, TRA.DE_STATE, REQ.DE_CLIENT, 
        REQ.ID_EXTERNAL, FAIL.CD_ERRORCODE, FAIL.DE_ERRORMESSAGE, FAIL.FH_ERROR_TIME, 
        FAIL.DE_STACKTRACE, REQ.FH_START_TIME, DET.SERVER_NAME, TRA.xml_message
        FROM    USER.PINGSOAREQUEST REQ,
           USER.PINGSOASERVICE SER, 
           USER.PINGSOATRACE TRA,
           USER.PINGSERVER_DETAILS DET, 
           USER.PINGSOAERROR FAIL
        WHERE   REQ.ID_SERVICE = SER.ID_SERVICE (+)
        AND     REQ.ID_REQUEST = TRA.ID_REQUEST (+)
        AND     SER.ID_SERVER = DET.ID_SERVER (+)
        AND     SER.ID_SERVICE = FAIL.ID_SERVICE (+)
        AND     REQ.ID_REQUEST = FAIL.ID_REQUEST (+)
        AND (REQ.id_soa IN ('bead47b1-86f3-4416-a3b7-212c38e3cf15')
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `LEFT JOIN` que es el estandar `SQL`, puede quedarte algo parecido a esto:

```
SELECT  REQ.ID_REQUEST, REQ.DA_USER, REQ.ID_SOA, SER.DE_NAME, SER.DE_VERSION, TRA.DE_STATE, REQ.DE_CLIENT, 
        REQ.ID_EXTERNAL, FAIL.CD_ERRORCODE, FAIL.DE_ERRORMESSAGE, FAIL.FH_ERROR_TIME, 
        FAIL.DE_STACKTRACE, REQ.FH_START_TIME, DET.SERVER_NAME, TRA.xml_message
        FROM    
           USER.PINGSOAREQUEST REQ
           LEFT JOIN USER.PINGSOASERVICE SER ON (REQ.ID_SERVICE = SER.ID_SERVICE)
           LEFT JOIN USER.PINGSOATRACE TRA ON (REQ.ID_REQUEST = TRA.ID_REQUEST)
           LEFT JOIN  USER.PINGSERVER_DETAILS DET ON (SER.ID_SERVER = DET.ID_SERVER)
           LEFT JOIN  USER.PINGSOAERROR FAIL ON (SER.ID_SERVICE = FAIL.ID_SERVICE)
           LEFT JOIN  USER.PINGSOAERROR FAIL2 ON(REQ.ID_REQUEST = FAIL2.ID_REQUEST)
       WHERE (REQ.id_soa IN ('bead47b1-86f3-4416-a3b7-212c38e3cf15')
```

Por favor tratar de ajustarlo a su caso en caso de ser necesario